# How to construct a Bit structure or class with sizeof == 1?

Tags: c++

I want to create a Bit struct or class which is of size 1 and is either 1 or 0
any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Clarification, Im trying to make an Implementation for Big Int in C++ which works like this

```
int foo() {
myuint<1024> i(5); // creates a 1024-bit unsigned int ’5’
myuint<2048> j = i << 1000 + 23; // shifts it by 1000 bits
// and adds 23
return j.template convert_to<int>() // returns 23
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a class or struct that has only one bit?

Comment: `struct Redundant { bool b; };`

Comment: `bool` meets all of your requirements. If you really need a class, we would need to see some examples of how do you want to use that class.

Comment: The smallest granularity `sizeof()` provides is 1 byte, not one single bit. One byte might be defined being less than 8 bits by the hardware architecture though.

Comment: See also: `std::bitset` and `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: @Austin Edited for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If dynamic allocation is fine then you can use `std::vector<bool>` to store the data:

```
template <unsigned size>
struct myuint {
    myuint() : data(size) {}
private:
    std::vector<bool> data;
};
```

`std::vector<bool>` is not guaranteed to use 1 bit per element, but most common implementations follow the recommendation.